# Cannot ssh into instance using gcloud

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine

I have set up a new instance in gcloud..yet am unable to use the `gcloud compute ssh instance-name` command. A verbose console output is:

```
debug2: bits set: 511/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: .....@..... (0x7fb5c12289f0)
debug2: key: ...../.ssh/id_rsa ((nil))
debug2: key: ...../.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: ...../.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_1000' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_1000' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_1000' not found

debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: ....@....
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Trying private key: ....../.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: ....../.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: ....../.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

I tried many things, one of the ways i found was to add my keys into the project's metadata..but isn't Google supposed to do that for you? It anyway did not work for me, and I tried creating a new google_cloud_compute.pub in ~/.ssh..still nothing. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried ssh through the browser from your developer console ?

Comment: yes that works just fine..however i need to move large files onto the VM.

Comment: You have a typo: your command above is `gcloud config ssh` but what you want is `gcloud compute ssh`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it ! :)

on my local machine, used

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine
```

and then tried the command. Worked like a charm!

Comment: You don't need to add the key to the SSH agent; `gcloud` picks up the key automatically from the path `~/.ssh/google_compute_engine` so this shouldn't be necessary... That said, glad to hear that it's working for you!

Comment: even i thought so..maybe it was a permissions issue. Glad it works now too!